# What kind of Bit Twiddling Hack is this piece of code?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

```
        int iHex = 0x42F4;
        int iResult = 0;
        Int16[] iLookupTable = new Int16[16];

        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            iLookupTable[i] = (Int16)(iHex & 1);
            iHex >>= 1;
        }
        if (iLookupTable[0] == 1)
            iResult += 0x8;
        if (iLookupTable[1] == 1)
            iResult += 0x800;
        if (iLookupTable[2] == 1)
            iResult += 0x4;
        if (iLookupTable[3] == 1)
            iResult += 0x400;
        if (iLookupTable[4] == 1)
            iResult += 0x2;
        if (iLookupTable[5] == 1)
            iResult += 0x200;
        if (iLookupTable[6] == 1)
            iResult += 0x1;
        if (iLookupTable[7] == 1)
            iResult += 0x100;
        if (iLookupTable[8] == 1)
            iResult += 0x1000;
        if (iLookupTable[9] == 1)
            iResult += 0x10;
        if (iLookupTable[10] == 1)
            iResult += 0x2000;
        if (iLookupTable[11] == 1)
            iResult += 0x20;
        if (iLookupTable[12] == 1)
            iResult += 0x4000;
        if (iLookupTable[13] == 1)
            iResult += 0x40;
        if (iLookupTable[14] == 1)
            iResult += 0x8000;
        if (iLookupTable[15] == 1)
            iResult += 0x80;

        MessageBox.Show("0x" + iResult.ToString("X"));
        // Output: 0x8317
```

I have disassembled and decompiled an old program that takes 16 bit hex number and after doing some kind of bit twiddling hacks it outputs the 16 bit result to screen, the above code is what it does, can someone tell me what kind of Bit Twiddling Hack is this code?

Comment: It extracts every bit in `iHex` into an array of int values representing those bits, then tests each "bit" and builds up `iResult`. Possibly some kind of funky endianness converter, but no way to tell

Comment: It looks like it's encoding a number by re-arranging the bits

Comment: I know the logic it uses to convert the input value, but i need the name of the way that it uses for the job, like the names in this page: [link](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html).

Comment: I doubt there's a generic term for it, other than "rearranging bitstring".

Comment: It seems you are true, because i have searched alot to know what it is. Anyway thanks for the reply.

Comment: It's some kind of encoding, that's for sure.  Maybe if you could shed some light as to the technologies involved we could link it to an actual known encoding.

It could also be a bit shuffle, for security.  E.g. sometimes programmers shift the way bits are stored in a variable to hide it from Memory Editors.  Especially true in video games.

Comment: @Ryios: This is the algorithm that an ECU EEPROM Programmer uses to change raw content before representing it as output to its hex editor or output file.

Comment: The generic term would be "bit permutation".

Comment: EEPROM, as in computer for cars/boats etc?  Is this a hobby, or work related?

Comment: Yes EEPROMs in the cars ECU. And yeah i only do this for hobby.

Comment: It's probably for a specific car or a specific type of ECU.  And it's probably an opcode translator.  E.g. maybe it converts 16 bit ASM to an OpCode language the ECU understands so you can program it with 16 bit ASM... Not sure, going on a whim.

Answer (score 2):

If you address the bits of the original number like this:

`0123 4567 89AB CDEF`

then it will rearrange them into this order:

`1357 ECA8 0246 FDB9`

That's all the odd numbered bits first, then all the even numbered bits, with the 2nd & 4th nybble in the reverse order of the 1st & 3rd nybbles.

OK, so now let's play:

```
    int iHex = 0x42F4;
    int iResult = 0;
    UInt16[] bits = new UInt16[16] {0x8, 0x800, 0x4, 0x400, 0x2, 0x200, 0x1, 0x100,
                              0x1000, 0x10, 0x2000, 0x20, 0x4000, 0x40, 0x8000, 0x80};

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        if ((iHex & 1) == 1)
              iResult += bits[i];
        iHex >>= 1;
    }

    MessageBox.Show("0x" + iResult.ToString("X"));
    // Output: 0x8317
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take the original 16 bits, and number them from 0 to F:

```
"0123 4567 89AB CDEF"
```

The rearranged value contains these bits in the following order:

```
"6420 9BDF 7531 8ACE"
```

This isn't a default operation I know of like a little to big endian encoding, but there certainly is a pattern in it. Maybe some value is being obfuscated, or this is part of an encryption/hash function.

Comment: OK, we used the exact same methodology, yet came up with radicially different orders -- what happend?

Comment: Dunno, did it by hand, may have made a mistake... odd/even groups are a fact though.

Comment: OK... If we reverse the two bytes, then reverse the order of the bits in each byte, they become the same.  But I think we can agree, it's not any standard operation.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the correct rearrangement that the code does:

Bit positions as:
`0123 4567 89AB CDEF`
To:
`3B2A 1908 C4D5 E6F7`

And this is the Decoder:

```
    private UInt16 Decode(UInt16 iHex)
    {
        UInt16[] bits = new UInt16[16] {0x40, 0x800, 0x4, 0x1, 0x200, 0x800, 0x2000, 0x8000,
              0x80, 0x20, 0x8, 0x2, 0x100, 0x400, 0x1000, 0x4000};

        for (int i = 0; iHex != 0; iHex >>= 1, i++)
        {
            if ((iHex & 1) == 1)
                iResult += bits[i];
        }
        return iResult;
    }
```